# Chaining operations and building an object with redux

Tags: javascript, node.js, redux

Below I have pieces of a redux implementation that I would like to conceptually wrap my head around.

I would like to use redux on the backend to help maintain control flow with code. I have simple functions below `getRequirerDir`, `getPathResolved`, and `getModuleResolved`. I would like to chain these three functions together using actions in redux, and I would like to build an object with the values returned. One of them is a promise. I have redux thunks implemented.

```
const start = (moduleString, requirer) => {type: 'START', moduleString, requirer}

const moduleString = './index.js'
const requirer = ''
store.dispatch(start(moduleString, requirer))

const getRequirerDir = (requirer) => path.dirname(requirer)
const getPathResolved = (requirerDir, moduleString) => path.resolve(requirerDir, moduleString)
const getModuleResolved = async (pathResolved) => await ModuleString.resolve(pathResolved)

// starting state
// {}

// ending state
// {moduleString, requirer, requirerDir, pathResolved, moduleResolved}
```

Comment: I find it interesting that you are using Redux with node since most Node implementations I have seen are stateless. Just wondering: why?

Comment: @Pytth I have an long operation where I am trying to maintain one large  object and manipulating it, I would like to see if it is possible to use redux to build and maintain that object, rather then passing it around through the code. I think about "state" here as the "state" of this single object. Like a large array of CSV data, or a list of URLS.

Answer (score 2):

Note: This may not fully answer your question.

This is an interesting question. And I noticed that you yourself have done th expected implementation. Kudos to that. However, maintaining app state in the backend is a bad practice. But there are instances that you may want to maintain state temporarily. If the said state stays for a longer period, I suggest you to use redis.

If not, there are different approaches to solve your problem. The most appropriate one I can think of for your usecase is SAGA. Using Sagas, you write your application as a state machine. This concept was used to implement the Redux-Saga library as well. However, you might want to implement the Sagas by hand or use a Saga library specially designed for NodeJs.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a full working example.

```
const thunk = require('redux-thunk').default
const { createStore, applyMiddleware } = require('redux')
const ModuleString = require('../ModuleString')
const Path = require('../Path')

function reducer (state = {}, action) {
  const {type, ...actionData} = action
  switch (type) {
    case _getDeps:
      return {...state, ...actionData}
    case _getRequirerDir:
      return {...state, ...actionData}
    case _getPathResolved:
      return {...state, ...actionData}
    case _getModuleResolved:
      return {...state, ...actionData}
    default:
      return state
  }
}

const _getDeps = 'getDeps'
const _getRequirerDir = 'getRequirerDir'
const _getPathResolved = 'getPathResolved'
const _getModuleResolved = 'getModuleResolved'

const actionCreators = {
  [_getDeps]: (moduleString, requirer) => async (dispatch, getState) => {
    await dispatch(({type: _getDeps, moduleString, requirer}))
    await dispatch(actionCreators.getRequirerDir(moduleString, requirer))
  },
  [_getRequirerDir]: (moduleString, requirer) => async (dispatch) => {
    const requirerDir = getRequirerDir(requirer)
    await dispatch(({type: _getRequirerDir, requirerDir}))
    await dispatch(actionCreators.getPathResolved(requirerDir, moduleString))
  },
  [_getPathResolved]: (requirerDir, moduleString) => async (dispatch) => {
    const pathResolved = getPathResolved(requirerDir, moduleString)
    await dispatch(({type: _getPathResolved, pathResolved}))
    await dispatch(actionCreators.getModuleResolved(pathResolved))
  },
  [_getModuleResolved]: (pathResolved) => async (dispatch) => {
    const moduleResolved = await getModuleResolved(pathResolved)
    await dispatch(({type: _getModuleResolved, moduleResolved}))
  }
}

const store = createStore(
  reducer,
  applyMiddleware(thunk)
)

store.subscribe(() => console.log(store.getState()))

const moduleString = './index.js'
const requirer = ''
store.dispatch(actionCreators.getDeps(moduleString, requirer))

const getRequirerDir = (requirer) => Path.dirname(requirer)
const getPathResolved = (requirerDir, moduleString) => Path.resolve(requirerDir, moduleString)
const getModuleResolved = async (pathResolved) => ModuleString.resolve(pathResolved)
```

Feedback / Optimizations welcome.